# Filter for files with embedded timestamp in the file name

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Let's say I have these files:

```
file-foo-1514764800.log
file-foo-1514851200.log
file-foo-1514937600.log
file-foo-1515024000.log
file-foo-1515110400.log

file-bar-1514764800.log
file-bar-1514851200.log
file-bar-1514937600.log
file-bar-1515024000.log
file-bar-1515110400.log
```

The timestamps in the file names correspond to Jan 1st to Jan 5th. If I want to filter for files which have the timestamps in the range `Jan 2nd` up to `Jan 4th`, I would need to write an expression such as `>= 1514851200 && <= 1515024000` (>= Jan 2nd && <= Jan 4th), and use it to filter on the third item in the file name, if we use `-` as the delimiter.

Note that in my case I can't rely on the modification date of the files, as they may have been modified at an arbitrary time. In such a case the solution is rather simple:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "2018-01-04" ! -newermt "2017-01-06"
```

What's a simple way to solve this using bash (zsh is fine too), and common linux tools?

Comment: What is `1514764800` in files, is it epoch time? Please confirm once.

Comment: Yes it's a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've one idea, not perfect but rather easy. Go to the directory of log files and run command below:

```
for f in *.log; do m=${f/*-*-}; n=${m/.log}; [[ "$n" -ge 1514851200 && "$n" -le 1515024000 ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

More details about bash parameter expansion: [${PARAMETER/PATTERN/STRING}](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace)

I checked this command line working in bash 4.4.12 and zsh 5.4.2.

Comment: This is a syntax error. The thing after `${` needs to be the name of a variable to operate on.

Comment: @tripleee ehm... thanks for pointing it out. I checked the command line in zsh which works but I forgot to check it in bash. It's my bad. I updated the command. Now it should work in both.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the date part, convert to regular date an touch the files using that date. Then use a regular find command

```
for f in *.log; do
    fdate=$(basename $f .log | cut -d '-' -f3)
    touch -d "$(date -d @$fdate)" $f
done
# as you wrote
find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "2018-01-04" ! -newermt "2017-01-06"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but I think you can do it with Awk.

```
awk '{ split(FILENAME, a, "-");
    if (a[3] >= 1514851200 && a[3] <= 1515024000) print FILENAME;
    nextfile }' /path/to/*
```

This obviously hardcodes an assumption about the number of dashes in the file name. Maybe you can use some other pattern to easily extract the date stamp if that's problematic (`substr` with an index calculated from the end of the filename?)

Comment: Awk might go crazy in interesting ways if the contents of the files are random binary, but the log file name seems to indicate plain old boring text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using no shell scripting, which does not alter the modification times of the files (assumes no pipe '|' characters in the filenames):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '^.*-[0-9]{1,10}\.log$'
  | sed -r 's/^(.*-([0-9]{1,10}))\.log$/&|\2/'
  | awk -F '|' '("/bin/date -Is -d@"$2 | getline line)
    {if(line >= "2017-01-06" && line <= "2018-01-04"){print $1}else{next}}'
```

Comment: `sed | awk`  can almost always be refactored to be just an Awk script. Awk doesn't have backreferences but you get the whole language at your disposal for picking apart the file name.